# python pandas: fluent setter for DataFrame index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there a fluent setter for index?  Something like `df.with_index(other_index)`, which would keep the data (the `np.array`) as is, but replaces the index with `other_index`?

A non-fluent way (that modifies an existing DataFrame) is:

```
df.index = other_index
```

I found a way that doesn't affect the original, can be generated on-the-fly without temporary variables (so, kind of fluent) and is a shallow copy (it doesn't duplicate the data itself; the same unique `np.array` is shared by both `df` and the result). However, is a bit verbose:

```
def with_index(df, index):
    return pd.DataFrame(data=df.values, index=index, columns=df.columns)
```

Alternatively:

```
def with_axes(df, index=None, columns=None):
    if index is None:
        index = df.index
    if columns is None:
        columns = df.columns
    return pd.DataFrame(data=df.values, index=index, columns=columns)
```

Is there some method that I missed that does that?  I tried `df.assign(index=other_index)`, but it just creates a new column called `'index'`...  And of course, `df.reindex()`, `df.replace()`, `df.set_index()` do different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doh. I just found it:

```
df.set_axis(other_index, inplace=False)
```

(Apparently, in a future pandas release, `inplace=None` will default to `False`, instead of the current --as of 0.25.1-- default to `True`).